# Creating a quizGame & Can't click any of the options and classes are added automatically. Is there a way to reset those classes for a new questions?

Tags: javascript

***HTML CODE***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quiz App By Sanan Shaikh</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- start Button -->
    <div class="startBtn">
        <button class="start">Start Quiz</button>
    </div>

    <!-- info box -->
    <div class="infoBox">
        <div class="title"><span>Rules of the Quiz Game</span></div>
        <div class="infoList">
            <div class="info">1. You will have only <span>15 seconds</span> per each question.</div>
            <div class="info">2. Once you select your answer, it can't be undone.</div>
            <div class="info">3. You can't select any option once time goes off.</div>
            <div class="info">4. You can't exit from the Quiz while you're playing.</div>
            <div class="info">5. You'll get points on the basis of your correct answers.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="quit">Exit</button>
            <button class="restart">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quizBox">
        <header>
            <div class="quiztitle">Awesome Quiz Game</div>
            <div class="timer">
                <div class="timeLeftText">Time Left</div>
                <div class="timeLeftNum">15</div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeLine"></div>
        </header>
        <div class="section">
            <div class="question"><span id="queNum"></span>.<span id="que"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="options">
```

***Below in optionList, class disabled, incorrectAnswer and correctAnswer are added automatically whenever I click on the next button***

```
                <div class="optionList" id="one">Hyper Text Preprocessor</div>
                <div class="optionList" id="two">Hyper text Markup Language</div>
                <div class="optionList" id="three">Hyper Text Multiple Language</div>
                <div class="optionList" id="four">Hyper Tool Multi Language</div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <div class="questionCount"><span id="update">1</span> of <span>5</span> Questions</div>
                <button class="next">Next Question</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="resultBox">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-crown"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="completeText">You've completed the Quiz!</div>
        <div class="scoreText">
            <span>Sorry!</span> You answered <span>2</span> out of <span>5</span>.
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="restart" id="playAgain">Replay</button>
            <button class="quit" id="Exit">Exit</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

***CSS CODE***

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
}

body{
    background-color: #dc143c;
}

.startBtn,.infoBox,.quizBox,.resultBox{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px 1px #79061d,
    2px 8px 15px 3px #610618,
    4px 12px 20px 5px #460512;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* start button styling */
.start{
    padding: 15px 50px;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #dc143c;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* infoBox styling */
.infoBox{
    width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
}
.infoBox .title{
    padding: 5px 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify-content: center; */
}

.infoList{
    height: 190px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.infoList span{
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #dc143c;
}

.buttons{
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    /* border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3; */
}

.buttons button{
    padding: 5px 30px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 2px solid #dc143c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.restart{
    background-color: #dc143c;
    color: #fff;
}

.restart:hover{
    background-color: #f10a38;
}
.quit:hover{
    background-color: #dc143c;
    color: #fff;
}


/* quizBox styling */
.quizBox{
    width: 650px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
}

.quizBox header{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.quiztitle{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.timer{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #fda0b2;
    padding: 6px 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.timeLeftText{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #dc143c;
    margin:0px 8px
}

.timeLeftNum{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    padding: 0px 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.timeLine{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12%;
    left: 0px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #dc143c;
}
.section{
    /* height: 280px; */
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 30px;
}

.question{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.options{
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.optionList{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 2px solid #dc143c;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color:#fddfe5;
}
.optionList:hover{
    background-color:#ffcad4;
}

i{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

.fa-check{
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    background-color:#d1ffd1;
    color:#008000;
}
.fa-times{
    border: 1px solid #dc143c;
    background-color:#ffc7d2;
    color:#dc143c;
}

footer{
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.questionCount{
    font-size: 17px;
}
.questionCount span{
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.next{
    background-color: #dc143c;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 2px solid #dc143c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.next:hover{
    background-color: #f10a38;
}

/* resultBox styling */
.resultBox{
    width: 550px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: none;
}

.icon{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.fa-crown{
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    border: 4px solid #dc143c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 8rem;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    color: #dc143c;
}

.completeText{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.scoreText{
    font-size: 17px;
}
.scoreText span{
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

***These are the classes***

```
.correctAnswer{
    background-color: #acfaac;
    color: #008000;
    border: 2px solid #008000;

}

.incorrectAnswer{
    background-color: #fc93a8;
    color: #dc143c;
    border: 2px solid #dc143c;
}

.disabled{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.show{
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

***JAVASCRIPT CODE***

```
let start = document.querySelector(".start");
let infoBox = document.querySelector(".infoBox");
let restart = document.querySelector(".restart");
let quit = document.querySelector(".quit");
let quizBox = document.querySelector(".quizBox");
let timer = document.querySelector(".timer");
let timeLeftText = document.querySelector(".timeLeftText");
let timeLeftNum = document.querySelector(".timeLeftNum");
let timeLine = document.querySelector(".timeLine");
let queNum = document.querySelector("#queNum");
let que = document.querySelector("#que");
let options = document.querySelector(".options");
let optionList = document.querySelectorAll(".optionList");
let one = document.querySelector("#one");
let two = document.querySelector("#two");
let three = document.querySelector("#three");
let four = document.querySelector("#four");
let update = document.querySelector("#update");
let next = document.querySelector(".next");
let resultBox = document.querySelector(".resultBox");
let scoreText = document.querySelector(".scoreText");
let playAgain = document.querySelector("#playAgain");
let exit = document.querySelector("#Exit");


let queIndex = 0;
let queNumb = 1;
let timeValue = 15;
let counter;
let counterLine;
let userScore = 0;

let questions =
    [
        {
            numb: 1,
            question: "What does HTML stand for?",
            answer: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
            options: [
                "Hyper Text Preprocessor",
                "Hyper Text Markup Language",
                "Hyper Text Multiple Language",
                "Hyper Tool Multi Language"
            ]
        },
        {
            numb: 2,
            question: "What does CSS stand for?",
            answer: "Cascading Style Sheet",
            options: [
                "Common Style Sheet",
                "Colorful Style Sheet",
                "Computer Style Sheet",
                "Cascading Style Sheet"
            ]
        },
        {
            numb: 3,
            question: "What does PHP stand for?",
            answer: "Hypertext Preprocessor",
            options: [
                "Hypertext Preprocessor",
                "Hypertext Programming",
                "Hypertext Preprogramming",
                "Hometext Preprocessor"
            ]
        },
        {
            numb: 4,
            question: "What does SQL stand for?",
            answer: "Structured Query Language",
            options: [
                "Stylish Question Language",
                "Stylesheet Query Language",
                "Statement Question Language",
                "Structured Query Language"
            ]
        },
        {
            numb: 5,
            question: "What does XML stand for?",
            answer: "eXtensible Markup Language",
            options: [
                "eXtensible Markup Language",
                "eXecutable Multiple Language",
                "eXTra Multi-Program Language",
                "eXamine Multiple Language"
            ]
        },
    ]

// click on start to start the game
start.addEventListener("click", () => {
    infoBox.style.display = "block";
});

// in the infoBox, click on  the exit to exit the game 
quit.addEventListener("click", () => {
    infoBox.style.display = "none";
});
```

***This is the next function I have created, It'll remove the show class from the next button until the user clicks on any of the options but, when I click next I'm not able to select any option plus the classes are from the previous question's answer still remains there in the next question.***

```
// click next to go on the next question
next.addEventListener("click", nextFun);
function nextFun() {
    if (queIndex < questions.length - 1) {
        queIndex++;
        queNumb++;
        showQuestion(queIndex);
        showQueCounter(queNumb);
        next.classList.remove("show");
    }
}

// in the infoBox, click on  the continue to start the game 
restart.addEventListener("click", () => {
    quizBox.style.display = "block";
    infoBox.style.display = "none";
    showQuestion(queIndex);
    showQueCounter(queNumb);
});
```

***ShowQuestions Function***

```
// creating showQuestion function
function showQuestion(index) {
    // 
    queNum.innerText = questions[index].numb;
    // 
    que.innerText = questions[index].question;
    // 
    one.innerText = questions[index].options[0];
    two.innerText = questions[index].options[1];
    three.innerText = questions[index].options[2];
    four.innerText = questions[index].options[3];
    next.classList.add("disabled");
    next.classList.remove("show");
    for (let items of optionList) {
        items.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let usersAnswer = e.target.innerText;
            let rightAnswer = questions[index].answer;
            if (usersAnswer == rightAnswer) {
                e.target.classList.add("correctAnswer");
                userScore++;
            }
            else {
                e.target.classList.add("incorrectAnswer");
                optionList = document.querySelectorAll(".optionList");
                for (let i = 0; i < optionList.length; i++) {
                    if (optionList[i].innerText == rightAnswer) {
                        optionList[i].classList.add("correctAnswer");
                    }
                }
            }
```

***Here, I have added disabled classes to all the options because if the user has selected any option , the user cannot select any of them again***

````
            for (i = 0; i < optionList.length; i++) {
                options.children[i].classList.add("disabled");
            }
            next.classList.add("show");
            next.classList.remove("disabled");
        });
    }

}

// creating showQueCounter Function
function showQueCounter(num) {
    update.innerText = num;
}


```[![second question before selecting any option][1]][1]
[![first question after selecting][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gFhs.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeN3m.jpg
````

Comment: Please try to give a minimum reproducible example of your problem rather than dumping large chunks of code.

Comment: Show exact problem its hard to understand the code in this way, or else make snippet instead of using code blocks, really couldn't understand where the problem is and what you want. At least remove css, which I don't think is related to issue here

Comment: @UtkarshTyagi noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through what I understood from the problem, I think you want to reset the classes for for options once user changes question.

You gave common class ('optionList') to all the options, whereas you add various classes based on the type of answer.

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll('.optionList')
const filterClasses = ['correctAnswer','incorrectAnswer','disabled','show']

const resetClassList = () => {
  options.forEach(option => {
    for(let j=0;j<filterClasses.length;j++){
      if(option.classList.contains(filterClasses[j])){
       option.classList.remove(filterClasses[j])
      }
    }
  })
}

resetClassList()
```

```html
<div class="optionList disabled" id="one">Hyper Text Preprocessor</div>
<div class="optionList show" id="two">Hyper text Markup Language</div>
<div class="optionList correctAnswer" id="three">Hyper Text Multiple Language</div>
<div class="optionList incorrectAnswer" id="four">Hyper Tool Multi Language</div>
```

Run the resetClassList funtion whenever user changes question. You can use jquery to select various elements this will help you shorten your code where you define each and every single element.

Here is link to fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/ywL0dczf/11/